# GUI FTP program capable of using public/private keys?

Tags: gui, sftp

I need a SFTP client that's a GUI and is capable of using public/private keys.  Filezilla claims to, but first gave me this:

The file '/home/xxxx/xxxx' is not in a format supported by FileZilla.
The file is also password protected. Password protected keyfiles are not supported by FileZilla yet.
Would you like to convert it into a supported, unprotected format?

Though this is really "meh," at least it's something.... But I think it kind of defeats the POINT of having a shared key. :(

See, I would like to DISABLE "PasswordAuthentication" in my sshd_config on my server, but in order to do that I need a client that can use the key files.  If I try to disable password authentication and use FileZilla (even with key), it would jsut give me an error: "
Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available
Error: Could not connect to server".

Halp?

P.S., gotta stress GUI. I'm sure I've run across a few Command Line programs in my Googling that did the same, but I dislike using the command line. ;_;

P.P.s., something like WinSCP for Windows.

Comment: WinSCP does seem to satisfy your requirements - was there something wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, comment below was meant to be here. XD

Comment: It would be very helpful if you posted what OS you are using. It makes a rather large difference.

Answer (score 1):

OP here again.

FireFTP won't connect with my PPK file.

That got me to thinking, maybe something's wrong with -it-.  I didn't know how to test it until I looked back at Nicholas' answer--"Why not use WinSCP?"  I keep forgetting about the handy tool we have called WINE.  XD

It works fine in WinSCP over WINE, and that's probably the best answer after extensive searching.

Comment: If you want to regain ownership of the question, you should associate your accounts. http://superuser.com/users/11679?tab=accounts#sort-top

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which platform you want it to run on (I know its not Windows), but if it is OS X, you should check out [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch).

Comment: Cyberduck is available for Windows, too.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't see where you mention what platform, but since you mention Wine, I'm assuming some Linux flavor. I use Krusader for KDE. Try Krusader. There's also Konqueror. any of the KDE applications will work with it as part of KIO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh keys easily in GNOME as well. The 'connect to server' command in nautilus can use sftp as well, and the authentication can be done via password or your ssh key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like WinSCP on Linux you could [run WinSCP under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8552&iTestingId=14943).